# Expanding large data frame based on data range

Tags: r

I am trying to expand below data frame (1M + rows)

`employee manager      start        end
1       59  476762 2010-01-07 2010-07-12
2       59  719005 2010-07-13 2010-07-19
3       59  710780 2010-07-20 2010-09-19
4       59  440891 2010-09-20 2011-11-28
5       59 2308591 2014-08-07 2017-10-31
6       59 1442078 2017-11-01 2017-12-23`

To the following

`employee manager      YearMonth
1       59  476762 2010/01`

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Please share `dput(head(df))`, where `df` is your dataset. You need to do: reshape to longer format, and then use `format`.

Comment: Thank you @yarnabrina apologies for bad question on first attempt

Answer (score 0):

I am new to R (maybe this is very basic), but I was able to find answers from multiple posts and websites and thought to share it below (maybe not the most elegant but it worked in this case)

```
`M <- Map(seq, df$Start ,df$End, by="month")

 DFM <- data.frame(
 employee = rep.int(df$employee, vapply(M, length, 1L)),
 manager = rep.int(df$manager, vapply(M, length, 1L)), 
 YM = do.call(c, M)
                  )  

 DFM$YM <- format(DFM$YM, "%Y/%m")`
```

Hope this helps someone one day !